# Creating Signed Cookies for Amazon CloudFront using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, cookies, amazon-s3

Amazon has introduced Cloudfront signed cookie recently in addition to signed url.

How can I got about to create a signed cookie using c#?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [AmazonCloudFrontCookieSigner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudFront/TCloudFrontCookieSigner.html) class

```
    AmazonCloudFrontCookieSigner.GetCookiesForCannedPolicy(
        "example/img.jpg",
        "keyPairId",
        privateKeyFile,
        DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
    );
```

Comment: Where do you get the key pair ID and the private key file?

Comment: @BrianLegg: From AWS Console. You get to download the private key only once upon creation.